# When using Mission Control on my Mac, sometimes windows randomly turn invisible

Tags: macos

Twice now I have run into the issue reported here:

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/35897695?hl=en

where on rare occasions when I use the 3-finger swipe up/down gesture to see all open windows using the Mission Control feature on my Mac, all existing Chrome windows turn invisible.  How do I get these windows to be visible again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by running the following command from Terminal:

`killall Dock`